# Why won't this code with Java generics compile?

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

class Scratch {

  public static class Test<N extends Number> {

    public void foo(Class<N> numberClass) {
      System.out.println(numberClass);
    }

    public void bar() {
      foo(BigDecimal.class);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Test<Number> t = new Test<>();
    t.bar();
  }
}
```

This fails to compile on line 12 (the call to `foo()`) with `incompatible types: java.lang.Class<java.math.BigDecimal> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<N>`.  I don't get it, because the generic `N` extends `Number`, and so I should be able to pass `BigDecimal.class` to a method which takes a `Class<N>` parameter.  TIA for any thoughts!

Comment: `Class<? extends Number>` would mean any subclass of `Number`. `Class<N>` means the *specific* type of `Number` denoted by `N`, which is unknowable inside `Test` because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html).

Comment: Java is a bit behind in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer really is that `BigDecimal` is not necessarily `N`. It is a little confusing because `BigDecimal` is within the `<N extends Number>` bounds, but the current instance's generic type argument can be any type that extends `Number`, but the `bar` method assumes `BigDecimal`.

Check this slightly modified version of the method:

```
public void bar() {
    new Test<BigDecimal>().foo(BigDecimal.class);
}
```

That method compiles. Why? Becuase `Test<BigDecimal>()` has `BigDecimal` as type argument.

When you call `foo(BigDecimal.class)`, you're *assuming* that `this` was instantiated with `BigDecimal` as type argument, which is not always true, and the the compiler is preventing a bug.

---

The error in your code would be similar to a hypothetical `bar()` method in `ArrayList<T>` that does `add("string")`, which would be wrong for the same reason (the actual array list instance may be created to hold integers, not strings, so the inside code shouldn't make assumptions)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose a caller did:

```
var t = new Test<Integer>();
t.bar();
```

then, `bar()` would pass a `BigDecimal` to `foo()`, which expects an `Integer`.